# Is there a way to add dynamic url_prefix to all routes in Flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a large flask application that's structured as shown:

```
app/
  - mod1/
  - mod2/
  - init.py
```

Each `modX` is using a Blueprint which gets registered to the Flask app in `init.py`. Each Blueprint specifies a dynamic `url_prefix` as shown:

```
modX = Blueprint('modX', __name__, url_prefix='/<regex("[a-z]{5,}"):code>/modX')
```

There is also a `url_value_preprocessor` function that depend on `code` being available when an endpoint at this Blueprint is called.

Now, my question is, given that here are a few of this modules is there a way to do the same thing (add a dynamic `url_prefix`) to the Flask app so that all Blueprints registered to it will inherit that url_prefix and I don't have to repeat the code for each Blueprint?

Answer (score 3):

You can [provide the url_prefix option during the call to register_blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#registering-blueprints) rather than hanging the option on each Blueprint definition.

Comment: Thanks @phro. I would still need to call register_blueprint for each blueprint and pass the url_prefix to each one individually. Although I could store the prefix in a variable and use the variable or write a wrapper function that does the blueprint registration adding in the url_prefix.

Comment: A wrapper was exactly what I was thinking, something with a default kwarg would get you most of the way there with no repetition.